# vscode, what is the shortcut for this (close/open function block)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

#### in vscode (ide)

[image]

how to click this icon, without mouse.

---

so closed become like this:

[image]

---

and opened like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### what worked for me

1. open the vscode search bar by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. write `>shortcut`

[image]

3. now it will open a table, search `fold`

[image]

4. now you will see in the command column of the table

   - `editor.unfold`
   - `editor.fold`
5. use that shortcut you see in the second column, or change it to the more comfortable one

[image]
[image]

---

> in my case, docs don't show the correct shortcut,
>
>  maybe also to you,
>
>  so see the first part for finding yours or create a new custom shortcut

### documentation say:

> the documentation suggests using these shortcuts, so try to use them too...

| shortcut | what it does? |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> | close |
| <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> | open |

the shortcut you are asking for is called `fold`/`collapse`

see here the PDF: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

and search `collapse` and you will find it!

[image]

> but in my case seems different,
>
>  so if don't work also for you see the first part.

Comment: seems to not work

Comment: ok, see your preferences, maybe is different

Comment: thanks, please edit the answer with the new correction pls

Comment: now changed to correct one.

Comment: ok, in my case is `unfold = ctrl+shift+ì` `fold =  ctrl+maiusc+'` thanks a lot!